# Iterating Through Python List Getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, list, loops, nltk, list-comprehension

Using nltk to generate a list of synonyms to based on an input list of keywords.

I'm getting "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" when nltk doesn't have a synonym (i.e., when "None" is returned).

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dictionary=PyDictionary()


inputWords = ['word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7','word8']

synonyms = list(dictionary.synonym(i) for i in inputWords
```

current output for synonyms:

```
[['syn1','syn2','syn3'],['syn4'],None,['syn5'],None,['syn6','syn7'],None,['syn8'],None]]
```

desired output for synonyms:

```
['syn1','syn2','syn3','syn4','syn5','syn6','syn7','syn8']
```

I tried:

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in synonyms for item in sublist]
```

The output:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

What do I write to return just the synonyms in a clean list? I prefer to use list comprehension.
Any help appreciated. I'm a python noob and can't find the exact answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more pythonic one liner:

```py
flat_list = [i for sublist in synonyms if sublist is not None for i in sublist]
flat_list
>>>
['syn1', 'syn2', 'syn3', 'syn4', 'syn5', 'syn6', 'syn7', 'syn8']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `None` values and use itertools -

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain(*[x for x in synonyms if x]))
```

Comment: might as well use `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(filter(None, synonyms)))`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
flat_list = []

for i in range(len(synonyms):
   if isinstance(synonyms, list):
      flat_list += i
```

Comment: You shouldn't use that. That is merely referencing the built-in `next` function, and is very confusing.

Comment: I read about it 10 seconds ago. But never done some damage in my scripts, but i just do some LSTM or RNN work.

Comment: Putting random, meaningless things *does damage your code* because it makes it confusing.

Comment: Not for me, the model is for later use,not the code but i recognize your point. Thx

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic way to do this:

```
result = []
for word in input_words:
    synonyms = dictionary.synonym(word)
    if synonyms:
        result.extend(synonyms)
```

If you *insist* on using a list comprehension, you *could* use an assignment expression:

```
[synonym for word in input_words if (synonyms:=dictionary.synonym(words)) for synonym in synonyms]
```

But I think the first option is much preferable.